Inject custom .css and .js from cloud to a android webview app
I am making an app just for one thing - phone diary (in my school they are going to block all native apps) so I am making my own. I barely figured out how to use webview in android, but managed to get it working.
Turns out the website isn't quite useful enough so I want to develop a custom *.css and *.js to make animations for css, effects, etc.
The contents should be stored on Github repo with all the sources (with raw.githubusercontent.com link).
For now, my activity to do what it does now (just open the website) it uses:
package com.fluid.dairy.foss // Such a failure in the first line, **dairy**. Well done, Fluid. Well done.

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity)
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String): Boolean {
                view?.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
        }
        webView.loadUrl("https://e-school.ryazangov.ru")
    }
}

I tried using converter to convert code from inject CSS to a site with webview in android answer but, even after editing I couldn't do anything about critical errors it was giving.
Every post I'm looking into uses local storage, while I need to automate the css/js updates via github, as I said above. If possible, please also add something to update the files on every launch so it will update every time.

Your question doesn't make sense.  How are they going to "block all native apps" as a school?  Unless they own your hardware and can prevent you from installing one.  They can't do it by traffic, because there's no difference between an HTTP request from an app and one from a web browser.  And this code your writing that displays a web view?  It's a native app-  the exact thing you said would be blocked.  So I'd rethink your entire approach here.  If they own the device and can block installation, this won't work.  If that isn't what's happening, what actually is going ot be blocked?

Their official apps are going to block, i dont exactly know how they are gonna do it, but i just included it
here for context

Yeah, that's not possible.  They can block installing apps, but to do that they need to own the devices and enroll them in Google Enterprise or a device policy owner.  And this approach would also be blocked because this is a native app.  They could block traffic based on a firewall (most likely) but in that case web vs native won't matter, just what URLs you go to .  You need to figure out what they're actually going to do, and address that.  Most likely it's the firewall, unless they own your device in which case they can block all apps, but it would include this type of app.

but i still need to get the app done though, they are not going to block it with HTTP request, the app is going to be useless because in Russia we are all going to use Gosuslugi to manage our accounts in Russian services, so it just wont log in

Like I said-  blocking all native apps isn't possible unless they physically can control the devices.  And if they do-  this approach won't work because it's a native app.  I think you need a better understanding of what's actually going on before continuing.
